# WIndows 8.1 in hibernation on boot up can't install Linux

Tags: linux, system-installation, dual-boot

I Have a HP Elitebook 2730p I cannot get Linux to install on it. it will boot up on the SD Card then loses it or dismounts it and cannot find it again to remount it to install Linux.

I then tried a live boot to see if I could at least get Linux to start on this &$^#&$ Laptop. when loading it. it came up and showed this error:

NTFS_fs device sda2 load_system_files() windows is hibernated will not be able to remount read write run ckdisk

How can Windows be in Hibernate mode on a cold boot or reboot?

I think that it why I Linux does not remount the SD Card when in goes into the Install mode ..

I turned off Hirbernate and hypernate(whatever that's called) they both are truned off still does the same error / warning

How to fix that, anyone?

thanks

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/145904/158442 - see the bit about Windows 8 and fast startup.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to disabling hibernation & fast boot, if you were to make enough free disk partition space in windows then you shouldn't need to modify your windows partition (sda2) to install Linux, you could just install to a new or empty partition you created from within windows.

But if you have a Windows 8 &/or EFI/UEFI laptop, you should probably read through the tips on this Q also: [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported) - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

I'm not sure about your SD card problems, but if your live Linux iso (cd/dvd/usb) supports the `toram` boot option (Linux Mint, Ubuntu, most Debian-based ones I think) and you have more than about 2GB ram, you could use that to copy all the required Linux data to ram first, then you wouldn't even need the live cd/dvd/usb to be connected to use live Linux system or install.

Comment: yeah I got 4GB Ram more searching and reading up on this problem Microsoft created I can see is needed -- thanks